# dfuse Websocket API cannot get signature in table

Tags: dfuse

[image]

Unable to get the signature in the table,But you can get the signature type from the parameters of the interface.They should be the same type.How should I get the correct push from the table?

```
client
  .connect()
  .then(() => {
    client.getTableRows({code:'pokereoshold', scope:'pokereoshold', table: 'gameinfo', json: true})
    .onMessage((message) => {
      if(message.data.dbop != undefined) {
        if (message.type === InboundMessageType.TABLE_DELTA) {
          if(message.data.dbop.new != undefined){
            console.log('222 \n', JSON.stringify(message.data.dbop.new));
          }
        }
      }
    });
    client.getActionTraces({ account: "pokereoshold", action_name: "reveal" })
    .onMessage((message) => {
      if (message.type === InboundMessageType.ACTION_TRACE) {
         console.log('\n\n111', JSON.stringify(message.data.trace));
      }
    })
  }
  )
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Unable to connect to dfuse endpoint.", error)
  })
```

this is my contract code

```
auto t_data = make_tuple(string("Holdem"), itr->bet_id, itr->player, itr->bet_asset, games.payout, itr->seed, itr->seed_hash \
                , games.sig, centercards, playercard, dealercard);
action(permission_level{ _self, N(active) }, _self, N(reveal), t_data).send();

auto gameitr = _games.find(itr->player);
if(gameitr == _games.end()) {
    _games.emplace(_self, [&](auto& info) {
        info = games;
    });
} else {
    _games.modify(gameitr, 0, [&](auto& info) {
        info = games;
    });
}
```

As you can see from https://eosq.app, I only wrote one table in my contract.

my contract "pokereoshold"   and table "gameinfo" 
Now running 10 seconds at a time

From https://www.eosx.io/account/pokereoshold?mode=contract&sub=tables&table=gameinfo&lowerBound=&upperBound=&limit=100 this connection can see the table, player = chenzhenfeng, every data in the table, every 10 seconds Will be new, but the content pushed by dfuse websocket is incorrect, only the signature is zero, the others are correct

Comment: Please use the code function of StackExchange instead of posting images. Other users will better find your question and it may load faster.

Comment: Maybe [related](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/dfuse-websocket-api-table-signature-shows-sig-k1-111111111111111)

Comment: Can you provide a link to a transaction that created such a message? I'm curious to see the raw data. The signature with a bunch of `1` you see there, is the normal serialization for a signature full of zeros.  It would simply mean it's empty.. no signature at all.

Comment: Also, tag the question with #dfuse so we can find it faster :)

Comment: From the blockchain browser, I can see that I wrote the table, and it is written once. Other types can be parsed. Only the signature is zero. I need this signature to verify the game lottery result.

Comment: I'm looking at https://eosq.app/tx/682bdc772a566c34f33b633e02129ed10f69a1e43ce6faaea0a059729bea6b54 and things seem in order (DB operations have the sig unpacked properly).  Since eosq is backed by dfuse, finding a page on eosq where the problem shows will help us pinpoint the issue very fast.

This page also seems okay: https://eosq.app/account/pokereoshold/tables?scope=pokereoshold&tableName=gameinfo Please advise, or join our Telegram channel https://t.me/dfuseAPI

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in dfuse API where signature binary data was not properly decoded leading to a default signature to be returned.

As of today (Januaray 20th, 2019), the bug has been fixed and deployed. So this should not happen anymore.